# .htaccess redirect mobile visitors to amp version

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, amp-html

I'm  using below code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/amp$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (2.0\ MMP|240x320|400X240|AvantGo|BlackBerry|Blazer|Cellphone|Danger|DoCoMo|Elaine/3.0|EudoraWeb|Googlebot-Mobile|hiptop|IEMobile|KYOCERA/WX310K|LG/U990|MIDP-2.|MMEF20|MOT-V|NetFront|Newt|Nintendo\ Wii|Nitro|Nokia|Opera\ Mini|Palm|PlayStation\ Portable|portalmmm|Proxinet|ProxiNet|SHARP-TQ-GX10|SHG-i900|Small|SonyEricsson|Symbian\ OS|SymbianOS|TS21i-10|UP.Browser|UP.Link|webOS|Windows\ CE|WinWAP|YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2|iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry9530|LG-TU915\ Obigo|LGE\ VX|webOS|Nokia5800) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)([\/]*)$ example.x/$1/amp [L,R=302]
```

The problem are the homepage `example.x` not redirect to `example.x/amp` and `example.x/a/b` not redirect to `example.x/a/b/amp`. It only works on `example.x/a` to `example.x/a/amp`.
I really need your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/amp$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (2.0\ MMP|240x320|400X240|AvantGo|BlackBerry|Blazer|Cellphone|Danger|DoCoMo|Elaine/3.0|EudoraWeb|Googlebot-Mobile|hiptop|IEMobile|KYOCERA/WX310K|LG/U990|MIDP-2.|MMEF20|MOT-V|NetFront|Newt|Nintendo\ Wii|Nitro|Nokia|Opera\ Mini|Palm|PlayStation\ Portable|portalmmm|Proxinet|ProxiNet|SHARP-TQ-GX10|SHG-i900|Small|SonyEricsson|Symbian\ OS|SymbianOS|TS21i-10|UP.Browser|UP.Link|webOS|Windows\ CE|WinWAP|YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2|iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry9530|LG-TU915\ Obigo|LGE\ VX|webOS|Nokia5800) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/-]*?)/?$ $1/amp [L,R=302]
```

Comment: it doesn't work either. the problem are still there.

Comment: Did you try to clear your cache or from other browser ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I checked through mobile-friendly test google and my handset.

Comment: cannot be reached, blocked by robot. my robot user agent block: /cgi-bin, /scgi-bin, /wp-admin, /wp-

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)([\/]*)$ example.x/$1/amp [L,R=302]
```

Assuming your amp version is under /amp (http://example.com/amp),

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/amp$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|googlebot\-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|\#opera\ mobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)([\/]*)$ https://example.com/$1/amp [L,R=302]
```

Comment: not working the homepage still not redirect to amp version